# Can I develop Android widgets using Sencha?

Tags: extjs

I am very new to Sencha.  Just wondering, if there is any possibility of developing Android widgets using Sencha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha uses HTML, JavaScript and CSS to build UI apps. It s not tied to native Android, iOS or other mobile platform components.  This is what makes it such an attractive proposition, you don't have to port your code to each device platform.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch is a good choice for web developers to build mobile applications. Sencha Touch is a HTML5 mobile framework. It helps you build mobile apps using Javascript and CSS.

In order to access the device's platform api's you can use PhoneGap. Its a deployment framework, with which you can access native apis like camera, phone book etc using just Javascript code. It also helps to package your application for Android or iPhone devices, which you can later publish in Play Store.